# React Swiper Style file edits are not saved

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js, react-native-swiper, react-swiper

swiper-bundle in my React project.min.i can't edit the css part, it doesn't apply the style when I edit and save, there are those who have the same problem in stackoverflow, I changed the color or something with the code I added below, but I'm trying to give pagination a width, maybe there are those who are experiencing the same, I'd be very glad if you could help.

```js
<Swiper style={{
        "--swiper-pagination-color": "#000",
        "--swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-color": "#8888",
        "--swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-opacity": "1",
        "--swiper-pagination-bullet-size": "9px",
        "--swiper-pagination-bullet-horizontal-gap": "4px"
      }}
```

I'm editing the style file and waiting for it to be active on the site.